# Is "nice" better than "ok"?

Tags: word-choice

I need help in a T or F exercise:

In the passage I have "The soup tastes OK." 
In a question I have "The soup tastes nice."?
Is it False?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you allowed "neither" as an option or even "not enough information"?

Comment: Do you mean 'is it true or false that the two sentences mean the same'?  _OK_ means _all right_, so it is not very enthusiastic praise of the soup. _Nice_ means that you like it, but there are better adjectives for food that you are enjoying.

Comment: @KillingTime Only True or False! So confused!

Comment: @KateBunting It's a True / False exercise:
The girl says " The soup tastes OK " 
The question is : "The soup tastes nice."     T  /    F

Comment: Without more information, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I think the soup taste ok- it's true

Comment: In the absence of other information I would choose *false*.  OK is not as good as nice.  Nice is on the good side of the spectrum. OK is adequate, average, passable.

Comment: 'nice' doesn't go with food. A person can be nice though.

Comment: We're not only guessing what the exact ranges along the execrable ... incredible spectrum 'nice' and 'OK' occupy in general (and 'exact ranges' implies everyone agrees), we're guessing (Mitch has a point, though I don't agree with him) (so fling in different ranges for different countries / regions / people) how these ranges are modified by the context (soup eating), and how felicitous the speaker's/rs' use of the terms is/are. / With a gun at my head, I'd reluctantly go with Jim rather than Razia. But Robusto is correct.

Comment: There's a wonderful scene in 'Yes, Minister' or its sequel trying to pin down whether "You're doing _all right_, Minister" was condemnation or praise.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn’t work well if it expects just a simple, definitive, binary answer.

It is true to the extent that a half-consumed glass of milk is still full of milk. “Okay” and “nice” have some semantic overlap, so one could argue for the statement to be True.

Alternatively, you could argue that it is False because if you asked someone, “Is it nice?” they could politely respond in the negative by saying, “It was ok.” Clearly, opposites don’t equate.

Nevertheless, that’s English for you - or *language*, more generally. Utterances can carry a lot more than syntax and dictionary definitions. The literary context as well as non-verbal cues can swing an interpretation one way or the other.

Comment: The notion that 'Okay' has a range of meaning/s / subsenses that overlaps in some hard-to-specify but exact way with the range of those of 'nice' makes or at least strongly connotes the assumption that the ranges themselves are not person-dependant. It's a wonder we can communicate at all.

Comment: With T/F questions as binary, isn't the test taker forced to say that with the neutral review, there's nothing to say the soup was mildly positive or 'nice'? The assumption that all questions are based exclusively on the written passages are usually explicit in such test instructions. No English, just logic.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a poorly constructed question and a good chance for the brighter students of the class to argue for points back regardless of their answer. "Was the soup disagreeable?" or "Was the soup exceptional?" would have been much better alternatives to elicit a T/F answer.